# AzureResponseError: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, cloud, azure-cloud-shell

I have cloned my app from GitHub into the Azure shell. When I tried to create and deploy the webapp I am facing few errors. First I tried `az webapp up -n newappname` and I got the below error

[image]

Then I created a web app myself in the portal and just tried deploying it from Azure shell using the command `az webapp up -n newappname_createdatportal`. I got the below error

[image]

Any suggestions here will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was a bug for old Azure CLI version, run `az upgrade --yes` and restart your prompt solve the problem for me.

Here are something to notice:

1. my Azure CLI version: 2.18.0
2. the command I use:

   ```
   az upgrade --yes
   #restart session and run this for authorizing
   az login 
   az webapp up -n webappnamecreated
   ```

Here is the reproduce screenshot:
[image]

Here is the successful screenshot:
[image]

Comment: My CLI is up to date already! Still, error persist!

Comment: Could you try re-install the Azure CLI to the latest version and run the command I post? It might be wired, but it seems this command is not compatible with your CLI, and the re-install might update something.

Comment: Btw, `az web app up` cannot use in Powershell on my computer, so I turn to use bash.

Answer (score 0):

I tried updating the `az` command line as other answer suggested but didn't work for me.

Instead of doing `az webapp up -n appname`, try first creating an appservice plan with application name `appname` then only after it has been deployed enter the command `az webpp up -n appname`. This worked for me.