# Ansible & Terrform issue - az login

Tags: azure, ansible, terraform

I am working with ansible,azure, terraform.

I have this role where I am initializing terraform but I am getting error.

```
---

- name: Check in Azure
  azure.azcollection.azure_rm_resourcegroup_info:
    subscription_id: "{{ subs}}"
    client_id: "{{ client }}"
    secret: "{{ secret }}"
    tenant: "{{ tenant }}"
    name: "{{ resource_group }}"
  register: info

- name: FAIL If Resource Group  exists
  fail:
    msg: "The Resource Group exists!!!"
  when: (info.resourcegroups | length > 0)

- name: Terraform start
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "Starting terraform"
    
- name: Initializing terraform
  ansible.builtin.command: terraform init -input=false
  args:
    chdir: "{{ my_dir }}"

  name: Create workspace
  ansible.builtin.shell: >-
    terraform workspace new my_workspace
  args:
    chdir: "{{ my_dir }}"
```

This is the error I am getting:

> Error building ARM Config: obtain subscription() from Azure CLI:
> parsing json result from the Azure CLI: waiting for the Azure CLI:
> exit status 1: ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.

It seems that I am missing an az login.
As I logged in with azure.azcollection.azure_rm_resourcegroup_info in the first task I was expecting it should not be necessary to do it again in this role.

I have tried to define the env variables in the playbook but its not working:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  environment:
    azure_client_id: "{{ client }}"
    azure_secret: "{{ secret }}"
    azure_subscription_id: "{{ subs }}"
    azure_tenant: "{{ tenant }}"
  roles:
    - create-my-vm
```

What would be the best way to do az login in order to proceed with all other tasks? If possible I'd like to use azure modules for this.

I have read the documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_azure.html

> If you wish to pass credentials as parameters to a task, use the
> following parameters for service principal:
> client_id
> secret
> subscription_id
> tenant

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the the Service principal Id and secret in the playbook script, Add it as a environment setting.

Refer this **[MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/ansible/install-on-linux-vm?tabs=ansible,azure-cli#)**:-

***Option 1:-***

Add your Service principal variables in the **`.azure/credentials`** file:-

```
[default]
subscription_id=subscriptionId
client_id=serviceprincipalId
secret=serviceprincipalPassword
tenant=serviceprincipalTenantId
```

[image]

***Option 2:-***

Directly set the variables in the terminal as Environment variables in the Terminal:-

```bash
export AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=subscriptionId
export AZURE_CLIENT_ID=clientId
export AZURE_SECRET=clientPassword
export AZURE_TENANT=tenantId
```

[image]

Now, You can refer these variables in your Playbook and run it.

Refer my [**SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75834215/azure-rm-webapp-permissions/75840223#) where I have ran the playbook in Azure DevOps, And fetched the service principal variables later for authentication.

Regarding terraform, Add your Service principal variables in your **`main.tf`** code itself:-

**`main.tf:-`**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.59.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  
subscription_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxb2a7"
tenant_id = "xxxxxxxxx5"
client_id = "xxxxxxxx35cb"
client_secret = "xxxxxxxGurfdsC"
features {
  resource_group {
    prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
  }
}

}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "azure-functions-example-rgsiddhesh"
  location = "West Europe"
}
```

**Output:-**

Authenticated with my Azure account as the plan was successful.

[image]